# Android In dutch language comma (,) is interpreted as dot (.)

Tags: android, kotlin, formatter, kotlin-android-extensions, decimalformat

I am using the following code to format the amount entered by user in EditText.

```
fun String.formatWithComma(): String {
    return try {
        val formatter = DecimalFormat("#,###,###")
        formatter.format(toDouble())
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        return ""
    }
}
```

But when I switch the phone language to dutch, the comma is converted to dot (.). Like if user wants to type 4,323 , it is converted to 4.323.

I want to comma instead of dot even in dutch language. Any solution

Comment: What's your question? Dutch uses comma as a decimal separator and dot as a thousands separator, so this behavior is correct.

Comment: I want comma instead of dot in amount formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Some European countries use comma and dot in the different way than USA and England. You should add an extra line to instruct it before you use it:

```
formatter.decimalFormatSymbols = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if this will fix your problem.

```
println("${"4.323.001".formatWithComma()}")
```

If we found multiple dots in the string, I am replacing that values, Improve this solution based on your needs.

```
fun String.formatWithComma(): String {
    return try {
        var lastIndexOf = this.lastIndexOf(".");
        var temp = this
        var temp2 = ""
        if(this.split(".").size >= 2)
        {
        temp = this.substring(0,lastIndexOf).replace(".","");
        temp2 = this.substring(lastIndexOf,this.length);    
        }
        
        val formatter = DecimalFormat("#,###,###.###")
        return formatter.format((temp+temp2).toDouble())
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        return ""
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your solution but
this solution works in case of 4.323.001 type of string only. Not works in 4,323.001

Comment: 4,323.001 it perfect string, you wan't to replace that last dot ?

Answer (score 0):

On the basis of answer given by [AIMIN PAN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72344481/14180770)

Final solution to fix this issue is

```
fun String.formatWithComma(): String {
    return try {
        val formatter = DecimalFormat("#,###,###")
        formatter.decimalFormatSymbols = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH)
        formatter.format(toDouble())
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        return ""
    }
}
```